# How to implement character sprite effects like in TowerFall?

Tags: unity, sprites

In TowerFall, the character sprites seem to dynamical stretch and compress with player action.

[image: towerfall gameplay with sprite effects]

Should I do this at the sprite sheet level? Should the sprites do this, or is there a better way to do this?

How would you achieve this in Unity?

Comment: This a classic Animation principle called [Squash & Stretch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haa7n3UGyDc), you can implement it in the spritesheet / sprite rig / model animation

Comment: You certainly could implement this by drawing the squash and stretch into the sprites themselves. Or you could try compressing/stretching their transforms at runtime. The choice is yours. Have you tried implementing it one way or the other, to evaluate the results you're able to achieve? If there's anything about your attempts thus far you're unsatisfied with, show us that, and we can try to help you improve the result.